# Trouble with setting RoundingMode on DecimalFormat

Tags: java, eclipse, decimalformat

This might be kind of a dumb question, but I'm stuck on it.

I'm trying to set the `RoundingMode` on a `DecimalFormat`.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

However, the code looks fine to me and it looks the same as many examples I have seen.

The error on `setRoundingMode()` is:

```
***The method setRoundingMode(RoundingMode) is undefined for the type DecimalFormat***
```

It suggests to cast `df` to an `Object`, but that doesn't solve anything...

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I am using ver. 1.7

Below I changed the compliance level to 1.6 yet no difference.

[image: Java Compiler]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: What version of Java are you using?  It looks like [`setRoundingMode` was added in 1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode-java.math.RoundingMode-).

Comment: @rgettman:Yes it is added in version 1.6

Comment: I have jdk 1.7.021 and jre7

Comment: @JosefE. Have you imported `java.text.DecimalFormat`? There exists `com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat` which doesnt contain the method

Comment: @Reimeus I have `java.text.DecimalFormat` imported

Comment: Have you imported the correct class for `RoundingMode`?

Comment: @EvanKnowles `java.math.RoundingMode`

Comment: Quick run this and see what it says: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));`

Comment: @DirkyJerky You solved it for me, thank you! The java on my machine is different that what the server is using. Thank you!

Comment: You've changed the compliance level to 1.6 of the compiler, what about the jre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` and be sure that your jre version really is 1.6 or higher